# oscilloscope time charging different from the math

Tags: oscilloscope, charging

[image]

For the above circuit, I calculate that the equivalent resistance of the charging circuit is **2.668 kΩ**, and the equivalent capacitance is **2.055 µF**. Therefore, the time constant would be `2.668*2.055 = 5.48 ms` as the amount of time required to charge.
I simulated the circuit and got the following time constant:

[image]

It is almost twice as doubled, while it should be approximately the same. Can anyone explain to me the difference?
Thank you.

Comment: Did you forget R4?

Comment: @BrianDrummond I thought R4 was for when the circuit is discharging.

Comment: You appear to have R4 in the wrong place. I think you intended it be in the circuit only when the switch is in the down position. Instead, it's in series when switch is in the up position, and produces a confusing result.

Answer (score 3):

As drawn R4 and R3 are in series making the equivalent charging resistor

\$ R = \frac{1.62 \cdot 1.78}{1.62 + 1.78} + 1.82 + 2.43 = 5.098 k\Omega\$

and capacitor

\$ C = \frac{1.4 \cdot 2.2}{1.4 + 2.2} + 1.2 = 2.055 \mu F\$

The time constant is therefore

\$\tau = C \cdot R = 10.47 \text{ ms}\$

As pointed out in comments you have neglected R4.  If R4 is only supposed to effect the discharge time it should be connected between the switch and earth.